# C#: TimeSpan subtract

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

How can I subtract my value of time minus one hour. I've tried with `Substract` but it shows some errors. First time is time of movie and a second needs to be time-1hour.

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.movie.Time)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.movie.Time.Substract(-1))
    </td>
```

The error is "Cannot convert from int to TimeSpan".

Comment: You could help by actually telling us the error! For a start `Substract` isnt a method name (or, a word for that matter).

Comment: You should not subtract in your View. Do it in your ViewModel.

Comment: Even if you want to do it in your View, you need to subtract a timespan. So something like `TimeSpan.FromHours(1)`

Comment: Error is: cannot convert from int to TimeSpan

Comment: so... a pretty good error then. Did you check the documentation for `Subtract` to see what parameter it takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add another property in your ViewModel which will be calculated one and use it in the view:

```
public TimeSpan CalculatedTime
{
    get
    {
       return Time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    }
}
```

and now use it in your View:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.movie.Time)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.movie.CalculatedTime)
</td>
```

Comment: `Time` is a `TimeSpan` and you are passing 1 as OP. But [`Subtract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `TimeSpan` not an integer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for pointing that, corrected it